# When does this Font object get disposed?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I have a line in my C# code that creates a font in order to measure the length of a string:

```
int width = (int)(myGraphics.MeasureString(text, new Font(myFontName, myFontSize, FontStyle.Bold)).Width);
```

My question is, when is the `new Font()` variable disposed?  Is it disposed when the form is disposed, or is it immediate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Font` has finalizer declared:

```
~Font()
{
    this.Dispose(false);
}
```

When font object created, it's registered in finalization queue. Such objects are not destroyed (i.e. memory stays allocated) during garbage collection - they destroyed later, when finalizers called (btw finalizer could be never executed). Thus better call `Dispose` manually or via `using` statement. In this case font object will be disposed and unregistered from finalization (thus it will be removed from memory during garbage collection):

```
public void Dispose()
{
    this.Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

You can read more about garbage collection and finalization [in Jeffrey Richter's article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx)

Comment: +1, the only correct answer so far, except that when you say "disposed" you really mean "removed from memory".

Comment: @KrisVandermotten thanks :) I made some improvements on answer

Comment: I didn't want this to be the answer (I wanted to rely on the C# GC), but after doing a lot more research ([I found this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/csharpgeneral/thread/ba9b136c-15b0-42bf-87b6-bdbe38f0b4c7)) I believe you are right.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -2):

It will be disposed whenever the garbage collector feels like.  You should not rely on using dispose for much because you cannot guarantee that it will happen soon.  You can rest assured that it will not be disposed until you are done using it however (i.e. no references to it exist within objects that are in scope)

Comment: Don't confuse disposing (on demand freeing of managed or unmanged resources), finalizing (freeing unmanaged resources that haven't been disposed) and garbage collection (freeing memory). Finalize is called by the garbage collector unless upressed, Dispose is never called by the garbage collector.